# WinMerge on Windows 10: RightClick Compare does not work

Tags: winmerge

In Windows 10, when using Windows Explorer, "Winmerge" context menu execution does not do anything. In other words, when clicking on the "WinMerge" option in the right-click contextual menu, nothing happens.

I've tried both WinMerge-2.16.0-x64-Setup.exe and WinMerge-2.16.0-Setup.exe

Comment: This was [posted as a bug out on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/bugs/2195/), but I'm guessing it didn't get attention because of the simple solution.

Comment: I also noticed that it takes about 30 seconds for WinMerge to launch, which may be why some are reporting the issue. After I answered below, I went to use the context menu again, and thought it was failing, but alas, it's just really slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem. The solution for me was:

- Checking the box "Add WinMerge folder to your system path".

Answer (score 0):

When running the -Setup.exe, make sure you right-click it, and select "Run as administrator". ;-) Yep. That simple.